# designing RMI client through java

Tags: java

I am using spring rmi that is i have designed a client program which will access my RMI service and i am using jdk 1.5 below is the program in which I have designed the rmi client in spring way , please advise i want to design this client through normal core java program

my **rmi service** are hosted and are started seprately below is the url

```
rmi://MW42:6212/acerwew
```

now below is the spring program that is RMI client which i want to convert it into normal core java program

below is the xml configuration **app.xml :-**

```
<bean id="rtebeans" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://MW42:6212/acerwew"></property> 
<property name="serviceInterface" value="com.tredler.trewq"></property>
</bean>
```

and below is the **class**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml");
          AcknowledgementMessageHandlerHome am = (AcknowledgementMessageHandlerHome) context.getBean("rtebeans");
        String message = "abc";
        String owner = "afgbc";
        String applicationId = "ahjubc";

          am.ert(ertyu, uiop, rdassw);
```

now please advise how can i design tand convert above through normal core java client program

Comment: By learning about RMI is a good start. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/

Comment: @John Please advise how can i design client

Comment: There is a full working example at the oracle docs provided.

Comment: please advise how can i customise it to add my services detials please